# Используются ли сейчас http заголовки при создании сайтов?

Tags: php, http, http-заголовки

**Весь вопрос, по сути, в заголовке.** Сейчас учу PHP и наткнулся на тему про HTTP заголовки, тема немного замысловатая, вот и думаю стоит им уделять много внимания или можно поверхностно пробежать и не забивать голову?

Comment: Используется ли сейчас html при создании сайтов?

Comment: Отвечу кратко без заголовки используются и зачастую генерятся сервером. Углубляться не стоит, ибо когда понадобиться всегда можно найти в гугле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой теме ничего сложного нет, если правильно понять протокол http.

Http1 - текстовый протокол прикладного уровня. Исходя из этого определения, все данные(url, headers, body) посылаются в текстовом виде. Да и сам запрос можно представить текстовой командой (например telnet).

Хэдеры очень часто используются для реализации авторизации (oauth, cookies). Так что это надо знать.

Answer (score 2):

Стоит изучить. В заголовках содержится часто много ролезной информации.
Например, при ответе в json формате правильно добавить информацию о контенте

header('Content-Type: application/json');

В этом случае некоторые браузеры (и соответствующие плагины) будут выводить информацию в структурированном виде, а не простым текстом который трудно будет читать.
Из заголовков можно узнать IP адреса серверов, используемых прокси, версии браузера и веб-сервера, имена и пути выполняемого скрипта и многое другое.